# SWFAddress, Back button

Tags: actionscript-3, swfaddress

Can SWFAddress "sense" when a user has pressed the browser back button?

I know it can fire off EXTERNAL_EVENTS, but...does it do this for specific buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, the only awareness that swfaddress has of the user pressing the back button is that the address in the browser's location bar changes (represented by the window.location object in javascript). It detects that change by checking the window.location object on a regular interval.

When the window.location object changes, but swfaddress didn't trigger the address change, it fires an EXTERNAL_CHANGE event. This could be caused by the user typing in a new anchor into the location bar, hitting the back/forward buttons, or several other things. There's no way to do something like putting an event listener on the browser's back button.